# What is the difference between \Centering and \centering?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ragged2e

My question is already written on the title above.

---

**EDIT 1:**

I attempted to use `\Centering` and remove `\arraybackslash` in my original code below. It cannot be compiled.

```
\documentclass[dvips,dvipsnames,rgb]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=10mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lscape}

\newcounter{No}
\renewcommand{\theNo}{\stepcounter{No}\arabic{No}}
\newenvironment{MyTable}[4]%
{%
    \newcolumntype{A}[1]%
    {%
        >{%
            \begin{minipage}%
                {%
                    ##1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth%
                }%
                \vspace{\tabcolsep}%
         }%
         c%
        <{\vspace{\tabcolsep}\end{minipage}}%
    }%
    \setcounter{No}{0}%comment out this if you want to continuous numbering for all tables.
    \begin{longtable}%
    {%
            |>{\scriptsize\Centering\theNo}A{#1}<{}%
            |>{}A{#2}<{\Centering\input{\jobname.tmp}}%
            |>{\Centering\lstinputlisting{\jobname.tmp}}A{#3}<{}%
            |>{\scriptsize\arraybackslash}A{#4}<{}%Please try to remove \arraybackslash here.
            |%
    }%
    \hline\ignorespaces%
}%
{%
    \end{longtable}%
}

\newcommand{\Comment}[1]{& & & #1\\\hline}


\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
language={PSTricks},
basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,%
keywordstyle=\color{blue}%,
%backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!30}%
}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}


\def\MyRow{%        
        \VerbatimEnvironment%
        \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.tmp}%
}

\def\endMyRow{%
        \end{VerbatimOut}%      
}



\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{%
gridwidth=0.4pt,%default: 0.8pt
gridcolor=Red!20,%default: black
griddots=0,%default: 0 
%
gridlabels=3pt,%default: 10pt
gridlabelcolor=Blue,%default: black
%
subgriddiv=5,%default: 5
subgridwidth=0.2pt,%default: 0.4pt
subgridcolor=Green!20,%default: gray
subgriddots=0%default: 0
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction to PSTricks}
\lipsum[1]

\section{At a glance galleries}
\lipsum[1-5]

%Landscape starts here.
\pagestyle{empty}
%\begin{landscape}
\begin{MyTable}{0.05}{.25}{0.4}{0.3}%
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture*[showgrid](4,4)
\pnode(1,1){A}
\pnode(3,3){B}
\ncline{A}{B}
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[1]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=red!30](3,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[2]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](4,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=green!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[3]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](4,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=yellow!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[4]}
%=============
\begin{MyRow}
\pspicture[showgrid](4,3)
\psframe*[linecolor=Maroon!30](3,2)
\endpspicture
\end{MyRow}
\Comment{\lipsum[5]}
%=============
\end{MyTable}
%Landscape stops here.
%\end{landscape}
\pagestyle{plain}

\section{Node}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\Centering` allows hyphenation, `\centering` not and it also can be used in tabular headings to centering the contents without using the `\arraybackslash` macro. Same for `\RaggedRight` and `\RaggedLeft`

```
\documentclass[a5paper,english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[originalcommands]{ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\centering this spaceframeconstruction spaceframe this spaceframeconstruction 
this spaceframeconstruction this spaceframeconstruction this spaceframeconstruction

\Centering this spaceframeconstruction spaceframe this spaceframeconstruction 
this spaceframeconstruction this spaceframeconstruction this spaceframeconstruction

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Herbert, thanks for answering. I will stop using `\centering` from now on.

Comment: Just a note that the command is not a standard LaTeX or standard LaTex commna but is provided by the ragged2e package  (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ms/ragged2e.pdf)

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides: Do not use URLs in that way. Use `http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/...` instead, without tex-archive and _with_ mirror

Comment: @Herbert, see my edit 1 above. Removing `\arraybackslash` will result in compilation errors even though you use `\Centering` instead of `\centering`.

Comment: I have no problem in running the above example with `latex`.

Comment: @Herbert. Actually, the general feeling is to use `http://ctan.org/pkg/<name-of-package>`.

Comment: @Herbert, Have you removed the `\arraybackslash` ? I also use latex.exe and but it cannot be compiled if I remove the `\arraybackslash`.

Comment: ok, a misunderstanding. For this column you do not have any setting of `\Centering` et-al. The reason why you need it here

Comment: @Joseph: correct, but that is the page of information not the link to the documentation. However, you should also use a mirror.

Comment: @Herbert, should I "throw away" `\centering` in my daily job using LaTeX? I still have no idea to choose one over the other.

Comment: @xport-is-sleeping: depends on what you  want to do. If hyphenation is useful then yes. In tabulars I always use it. But in floating environments I always still use `\centering`.

Comment: @Herbert, return to your answer. Is the use of `\arraybackslash`  irrelevant to whether we use `\Centering` or `\centering` ?

Comment: @Herbert Thanks about the comment with the url. I am not sure though if I agree with you on the hyphenation part of the answer. This for example will hyphenate the word. `\begin{minipage}{2cm}` 
`\centering{this spaceframeconstruction}` 
`\end{minipage}`

Comment: You do not need `\arraybackslash` when you have a `\Centering` et al here. But in your case it is a bit more complicated, because you use the >{} twice, in your column definition _and_ in your tabular header. The reason why it is not easy (maybe not possible) to pass a `\Centering` in the needed way into the longtable  definition that it always get the needed information from `\Centering`.  A `\arraybackslash` in this special case may always be needed. I never used it in that way, the reason why I cannot give more informations here, sorry.

Comment: @Herbert. Sorry, but at least from my geographical location that will fail, as not all of the mirrors include the `pkg/<packagename>` links.

Comment: @Joseph: Your are absoluetely right. I didn't know that the /pkg directory isn't below the tex-archive one. So the mirror won't work here.

Comment: @yiannis: see my edited example in the answer